# Can I brew a Lightning Bolt potion? What does it do?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, potions

If I brew a *potion of [lightning bolt](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/lightningBolt.htm)*, what happens when someone drinks it?

- *Lightning bolt* strikes them?
- They can cast a *lightning bolt*?
- They emit lightning that strikes where they point?
- Nothing happens?

Same thing with *[vampiric touch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/vampiricTouch.htm)*: Would the consumer covert their hit points to temporary hit points? Would that mean that drinking a healing potion after the *potion of vampiric touch* gives the character full hp + temporary hp without touching anyone?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A potion of [*lightning bolt*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/lightningBolt.htm) would not be a legal potion. The Feat [Brew Potion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#brewPotion) states which spells can be turned into potions:

> You can create a potion of any 3rd-level or lower spell that you know and that targets one or more creatures.

*Lightning bolt* doesn't have a Target, only a Range and Area.

If you allow potions of *lightning bolt* anyway, the most likely way that they would work would be to hit the imbiber with a lightning bolt.  Whether or not it hits any other targets would be pure DM fiat.

[*Vampiric touch*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/vampiricTouch.htm) is a valid spell to put into a potion, since it targets a creature.

The [rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/potionsAndOils.htm) on potions state:

> The drinker of a potion is both the effective target and the caster of the effect

It works just as you say; you drink the potion, take damage, gain temporary HP, and then can heal yourself back up to full with the extra temporary HP.